# Uncaught TypeError: web.get_url is not a function

Tags: sharepoint-server, jsom

When trying to execute the following code i got the mentioned error.
Here is the snippet:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
clientContext.load(web);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Get, Failed);

function Get()
    {
       alert(web.get_url());
    }
function Failed()
    {
       alert('Failed' + args.get_message());
    }
```

I've tried it on root site (/sites/root) and subsite (/sites/root/subsite/), still the same.

Thanks.

UPD

When trying to execute this snippet:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
console.log(clientContext)
var web = clientContext.get_web()
console.log(web)
var subsites = web.get_webs();
console.log(subsites)

clientContext.load(subsites);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(s, a)
{   
    var userInfo = [];
    var siteenum = subsites.getEnumerator();
    while (siteenum.moveNext())       
        {
        var oweb = siteenum.get_current();
        var webtitle = oweb.get_title();
        userInfo.push(webtitle);
        }
    console.log(userInfo.join('')); 
}
);
```

i got the following:

> SP.ClientContext {$r_0: Object, $1P_0: "/sites/root", $1O_0: Object,
>   $8_0: SP.ClientRequest, $O_1: SP.Web…} SP.Web {$0_0: SP.ClientContext,
>   $4_0: SP.ClientObjectData} SP.WebCollection {$0_0: SP.ClientContext,
>   $4_0: SP.ClientObjectData}
>
> site1 site2 site3

But when adding

```
var weburl = oweb.get_url();
userInfo.push(webtitle + weburl);
```

The error is still the same:

> Uncaught TypeError: oweb.get_url is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Probably the "sp.js" isn't loaded yet or isn't loaded correctly.

Try to use this code**:

```
var clientContext;
var website;

// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
// code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

// Create an instance of the current context and get the website.
function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    website = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(website);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
    alert('URL of the website: ' + website.get_url());
}
function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

**The example in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246877.aspx

Comment: Thanks but already tested this one. Still the same error (Uncaught TypeError: website.get_url is not a function). The following code works: 
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var site = ctx.get_site();
ctx.load(site);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(s, a){alert(site.get_url())});  So looks like sp.js is loaded as context can be found.